# How do I safely close my cadence client when my program exits?

Tags: cadence-workflow, uber-cadence

I have multiple things I am using in my cadence client

```
com.uber.cadence.worker.Worker.Factory
com.uber.cadence.worker.Worker
com.uber.cadence.client.WorkflowClient
com.uber.cadence.serviceclient.WorkflowServiceTChannel
com.uber.cadence.client.ActivityCompletionClient
```

Right now, even when my service has started exiting, activity pollers end up picking stuff and fail. What all should I close and in what order to ensure that none of my activities fail due to one of my service instances going down?

I am using `group: 'com.uber.cadence', name: 'cadence-client', version: '2.7.8'`